# SyntaxProblem. How to fill double List the same way how I filled the double array at the bottom in comments

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

How to fill double List the same way how I filled the double array at the bottom in comments.

```java
byte b;
short s;
int i;
long l;

private List<List<Product>> products = new ArrayList<>();
private Product[][] productsArray = new products[4][5];

public Automat(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            products.get(0).get(j) = new Product(b);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the image below, `products.get(0).get(j)` is getting flagged as a syntax error:

[image]

Comment: Kindly, add the code not the screenshots!

Comment: You should add code here then we can test it and give answer

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @HarshalParekh - two reasons. First, many people's sites block attachments, and many other people who would otherwise be helpful refuse to download attachments for the same reason others block them. Second, screenshot images make it impossible for someone to copy the code and test it in their own system.

Comment: @EdStevens, I know, I am letting the OP know about the same. If you go on the link, you'd understand.

Comment: @HarshalParekh  -  Ah, in my coffee-starved speed reading, I failed to notice that the text was a link, and not you actually asking the question.  Mea culpa.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign value using `=` to an index position of an ArrayList. You have to use [arrayListObject.set(index, object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)).

Example:

```
products.get(0).set(j, new Product(b));
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.